# function - printed exeption is used as returned value

Tags: powershell

I have two functions

1.
function getSQLServerData
return any sql data (if ok - return data, if error - print exception and return $null)

2.
function getAllCustomers
call function getSQLServerData...

```
@allcustomers = getSQLServerData -conn $connection -query $q
```

The problem occurs when the system detects an exception in function getSQLServerData and print it. Because printed exeption is used as returned value.

Exist any clear method how to solved tihs?

I don't understand, why print output is used as value, when valid return value exists.

PS:
When I think of a clean solution, I mean any switch that switches function form mode "all outputs as return value" to "return only value as return value" or something like this :-).

```
function getSQLServerData
{
param(
    [PSObject] $sci,    #SqlConnectionInfo
    [string] $q
)

    if($debug){write-host "processing...    " $q}
    try{
        if($sci.w)
        {
            $connectionString = "Server="+$sci.s+";Database="+$sci.d+";Connect Timeout=3;Integrated Security=True;"
        }
        else
        {
            $connectionString = "Server="+$sci.s+";Database="+$sci.d+";Connect Timeout=3;Integrated Security=False;uid="+$sci.u+"; pwd="+$sci.p+";"
        }
        if($debug){write-host $connectionString}

        $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
        $connection.Open()

        $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
        $command.CommandText = $q

        $result = @()
        $result = $command.ExecuteReader()

        $table = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
        $table.Load($result)
        $connection.Close()

        return $table
    }
    catch [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException]
    {
        write-host "SQL Error"
        write-host "Exeption: {0}" $_.Exception.Message
      return 1
    }
    catch [System.SystemException]
    {
        write-host "Unknown error"
        write-host "Exeption: {0}" $_.Exception.Message
      return 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Well i cant confirm it myself but have you tried just forwarding the stderr to $0 ?

Maybe try it like this: 
@allcustomers = getSQLServerData -conn $connection -query $q 2> $null

Comment: Can you show us the full definition of `getSQLServerData`?

Comment: to paxz. If I use > $null, all output is lost. Both - the data and the Exception.

Comment: I added funciont to qestion...

Comment: just to be sure, you did use 2> $null and not > $null did you?

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: What is the stacktrace? How can I do it in powershell?